# Move property value into text box using NSIS script

Tags: nsis

I have created nsi file for my java project.I have created a Textbox and gave as default value.My problem is running the exe file it displays textbox with default value.If the user  wants to modify the value in text box that should be Written in property file.I have tried following lines code

```
 InstallOptions::dialog "$PLUGINSDIR\sample.ini"
    ReadINIStr $0 "$PLUGINSDIR\sample.ini" "Field 1" State
    ${ConfigWrite} "$INSTDIR\resource\conf.properties" "AGENT.HOST" "=$0" $R0
```

But the modified values will be affected in property file.I dont know why this isnot reflected? can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include TextFunc.nsh

Function pageConfig
InitPluginsDir

# For this example I generate the page directly with the precompiler, you probably want to use a real .ini file.
!tempfile SRCINI
!appendfile "${SRCINI}" "[Settings]$\nNumFields=1$\n"
!appendfile "${SRCINI}" "[Field 1]$\n"
!appendfile "${SRCINI}" "Type=Text$\n"
!appendfile "${SRCINI}" "Left=10$\nRight=100$\nTop=10$\nBottom=24"
File "/oname=$PluginsDir\cfgpage.ini" "${SRCINI}"
!delfile "${SRCINI}"

ClearErrors
${ConfigRead} "$INSTDIR\resource\conf.properties" "AGENT.HOST=" $0
${If} ${Errors}
    StrCpy $0 "DefaultHost.com"
${EndIf}
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\cfgpage.ini" "Field 1" "State" $0

InstallOptions::dialog "$PluginsDir\cfgpage.ini"
Pop $0
FunctionEnd

Function pageLeaveConfig
ReadINIStr $0 "$PluginsDir\cfgpage.ini" "Field 1" State
${If} $0 == ""
    MessageBox mb_iconstop "Please provide a host..."
    Abort
${EndIf}
${ConfigWrite} "$INSTDIR\resource\conf.properties" "AGENT.HOST=" "$0" $1
FunctionEnd


Page custom pageConfig pageLeaveConfig
```

Comment: @sekt thanks.while installing i have modified value for AGENT.HOST value.but after installation i saw default value only.modified value not yet reflected.i dont know y?

Comment: @seki thanks.I have used Exec command then its working fine.thank you for support.